# Ways of checking the Version of my MediaWiki?

Tags: html, version, upgrade, mediawiki, wiki

I just updated my MediaWiki to Version 1.25.3. At least that is what i think i did. Everything seems to work fine. I copied the new files into my folder, and replaced the LocalSettings.php with my old one. Also updated some Extensions and copied my old images folder - just like it says [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading/de#Upgrade_extensions). I do not have access to our database yet, but everything seems to work so far.

My problem: I did not find any reliable way to asses the version. If i navigate to *special:version* it still shows the old version: 1.23.6

I verified the files somewhat, and they seem to be the new ones. Is there any other way i can check this?

If i try to use some of the newer features, such as this new way of including extensions & skins:

```
wfLoadExtension( 'Cite' );
wfLoadExtension( 'Gadgets' );
wfLoadExtension( 'ImageMap' );
wfLoadExtension( 'InputBox' );
```

but it **won't work**. I am getting:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wfLoadExtension()
```

That might be due to my highly customized version of the Wiki (Custom skin etc.), but it might also be, because of an error with the update?

Has anyone got any idea what is going on?

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that Anyone cares, but i managed to fix the Problem. Turns out, i did not actually do an Update. That is why i could not see the correct version number. Did the Upgrade now, and everything works as expected.

I can see my version on special:version